# cache issues O_SYNC for my device driver shared memory

Tags: c, linux, kernel, mmap

I just implemented a kernel module for new device.
This device support a shared memory host and target.
I encountered some cache coherence issues.
when I update the data in target of this variable the host can't read the real data by the host.
I tried to use O_SYNC when I open my device but it doesn't work(probably due to its not dev/mem device)

how can I implement O_SYNC when I use my device?

Comment: So basically the problem is you map some target memory on the host but the host is still using its cache and you don't want the host to use its cache. O_SYNC has nothing to do with it since that bypasses the kernel's cache, not the processor's.

Comment: Does your kernel module use the dma_ functions to access the memory?

Comment: No, the module just support shared mem user space - kernel.

Comment: there is any way how can i enforce reading or writing to the DRAM?

Comment: Shared mem user space - kernel is not the problem. I bet the kernel has the exact same caching problems. The problem is between the driver (kernel module) and the hardware. Please show how the driver gets access to the memory

Comment: This is a very common problem with device drivers and I'm sure the kernel has API functions to set it up correctly, perhaps even by default - my suspicion you're bypassing the kernel APIs (e.g. just hardcoding the address) so the CPU doesn't get told not to cache this

Comment: this mmap example demonstrates the kernel<->user part but not the hardware<->kernel part which is where the problem is

Comment: Oh i see, any idea where to start ?

Comment: I repeat: Please show how the driver gets access to the (hardware's) memory

Comment: file_d = open(DEV_NAME, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

Comment: DEV_NAME is my new device that i wrote kernel module for him

Comment: so the **kernel module** calls `file_d = open(DEV_NAME, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);`??

Comment: to be clear: the driver and the kernel module are the same thing

Comment: no the kernel only map by : info->data=addres

Comment: what is addres?